# Vue: Vue Router is not navigating to any routes

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I am a newbie to Vue Js, and created a Vue project with `@vue/cli` 4.5.11.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import App from './App.vue';
import TeamsList from './components/teams/TeamsList.vue'
import UsersList from './components/users/UsersList.vue'

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        { path:'/teams',component:TeamsList},
        { path:'/users',component:UsersList}
    ]
});

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);

app.mount('#app');
```

But my app is not navigating to respective routes, and it's appending `/#` for every route.

Comment: I have used VueRouter with Vue 2 but haven't used Vue 3 yet, so not sure if this is necessary in Vue 3, but you might need to add Vue.use(VueRouter).

Comment: Which version of Vue Router are you using?

Comment: "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue 3 requires Vue Router 4 or newer, so you have to update that dependency:

```
npm i -S vue-router@4
```

Relevant Vue Router 4 migration guide:

- [`new Router` becomes `createRouter`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#new-router-becomes-createrouter) ([`createRouter`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#createrouter))
- [New `history` option to replace `mode`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#new-history-option-to-replace-mode) [(`createWebHistory`)](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#createwebhistory)

*Example:*

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [/*...*/]
});

//...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Have tried with Create Router before was not working because of router version issue. but  with router version update to npm i -S vue-router@4 createRouter working fine and able to navigate now.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the way you import your Vue Components, you can do the following:

```
component: () => import('./components/teams/TeamsList')
```

Here's an example inside the routes array:

```
routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/teams',
    name: 'Teams',
    component: () => import('./components/teams/TeamsList')
  }
]
```

Also, try to always add a default `'/'` path for unrecognized routes.

Comment: Hi, replaced with dynamic imports as you suggested Now, /# appending is not happening but not routing to any page and in console its saying runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:38 [Vue warn]: A plugin must either be a function or an object with an "install" function.runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: router-view.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution

vue-router version 4 or newer is working for **Vue3**.
`"vue-router": "^3.5.3"` is working for **Vue2**.